# How to prove a sequence is bounded above or below

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How do i prove a sequence is bounded above or below?
For a sequence like $\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ the limit will be 0 as x --> infinity but that doesnt tell me about the bounds?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Every convergent sequence is bounded .

Comment: How do i tell if it is bounded above, below or both?

Comment: When sequence is bounded it means that sequence is bounded above and bounded below .

Comment: I should've phrased the question better but the question on my sheet says is it bounded or not and if so is it above, below or both and prove it.

Comment: You say "sequence", so $x$ is a positive integer?

Comment: Both is the answer .

Comment: See this : http://mathonline.wikidot.com/proof-that-convergent-sequences-are-bounded

Comment: Thanks for the link, i got a few questions if you dont mind answering, im really new to this.. First of all is the maximum value Ap or 1 + L? Also how to work out the minimum value.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}\underset{x\to +\infty}{\to}0\iff \forall \varepsilon>0,\exists A>0, s.t.\quad  x>A\implies |f(x)|<\varepsilon$
That means f is bounded   on $(A,+\infty)$

As $f$ is continuous on $[0,A]$ according the Extrem Value Theorem $f$ is bounded on $[0,A]$,  $|f|<M$

Now we take $M'=\max(\varepsilon, M)$ then $|f|<M'$ on $[0,+\infty)$

Comment: ok i think i know what that means according to the link given above :D but how do i show its bounded below too

Comment: $|f|<M$ means $-M<f<M$

Comment: thancs for the explanation

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: hey i got another question i understood the first line but i dont get the second line, we havent done extreme value theorem yet so i dont know whether i should include the second and third line in my answer i dont really know what the third line means either

Comment: So it's better to use the solution given by @Melih İşeri, in fact, there are different manners to study sequences. For this one your sequence is $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}\quad n\to f(n)$ So you have to study the function $f :x\to f(x)$ because what it is right for $\mathbb{R}$ is right for $\mathbb{N}$ since $\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{R}$

Comment: To explain my proof, the first part says that $-\varepsilon<f<\varepsilon$ on $(A,+\infty)$, the 2nd part says $-M<f<M$ on $[0,A]$ And the third part we conclude with $M'=\max(M,\varepsilon), \quad -M'<f<M'$ on $[0,A]\cup(A,+\infty)=[0,+\infty)$

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is it a sequence defined on $\mathbb{N}$ or a continuous function defined on $[0,\infty)$?

Let $f(n) = \frac{n}{n^2+1}$. You can show

$f(n+1) \leq f(n)$

hence it is decreasing. Therefore $f(1)$ is the upper bound.
(Lower bound is 0)

If $f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2+1}$, then find the solution of $f'(x)=0$, and verify that it is the maximum.

Comment: The sequence is defined for all real values of x. Also, i plotted the graph of that sequence and it has a maximum at 0.5 and minimum at -0.5 so how do i show this without plotting a graph because then its not strictly decreasing or increasing

Comment: Then it is a function, when you say sequence people tend to think a function defined from $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$. You can still find solutions of $f'(x)=0$, which will give you the upper and lower bounds as $1/2$ and $-1/2$.